# Adding node to existing cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: cluster-computing, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster running on 2 machines (master-minion node and minion node). I want to add a new minion node without disrupting the current set up, is there a way to do it?

I have seen that when I try to add the new node, the services on the other nodes stops it, due to which I have to stop the services before deploying the new node to the existing cluster.

Comment: Can you update the question with more detail about the `kuberntes` version and platform you are using?

Comment: This might be a duplicate I answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654772/how-to-add-new-kubernetes-minion-to-current-cluster?rq=1 As Navid requested, to get an answer for exactly how to do it more will need to be known about exactly how you deployed your current infrastructure.

Answer (score 39):

To do this in the latest version (tested on 1.10.0) you can issue following command on the masternode:

`kubeadm token create --print-join-command`

It will then print out a new join command (like the one you got after `kubeadmn init`):

`kubeadm join 192.168.1.101:6443 --token tokentoken.lalalalaqyd3kavez --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:complexshaoverhere`

Comment: For any recent version of k8s, this is the correct answer.

Comment: what if the cluster wasn't created by using kubeadm?

Comment: I think only the kubeadm can create a new join command. How did you create the cluster?

Answer (score 12):

You need to run kubelet and kube-proxy on a new minion indicating api address in params.

Example:

```
kubelet --api_servers=http://<API_SERVER_IP>:8080 --v=2 --enable_server --allow-privileged
kube-proxy --master=http://<API_SERVER_IP>:8080 --v=2
```

After this you should see new node in

```
kubectl get no
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was due to an existing wront Route53 "A" record.
Once it's been updated to point to internal IPs of API servers, kube-proxy was able to reach the masters and the node appeared in the list (`kubectl get nodes`).