# Certificate key when adding node to Kubernetes control plane

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

So I know how to add a worker node to an existing Kubernetes 1.14 cluster (that was set up with `kubeadm`): [`kubeadm token create --print-join-command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322038/adding-node-to-existing-cluster-in-kubernetes) will print a valid `kubeadm join` command with correct values for arguments `--token` and `--discovery-token-ca-cert-hash`.

I currently understand that for adding another node to the control plane (master node) [`kubeadm join`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#stacked-control-plane-and-etcd-nodes) requires the additional arguments `--experimental-control-plane` (w/o value) and `--certificate-key`. This is for stacked control plane and etcd nodes.

How (in which file) can I obtain the correct value for `--certificate-key` for an existing cluster?

**UPDATE** My first (and currently only) master node was created without the argument `--experimental-upload-certs` to `kubeadm init` (but by `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` instead). Therefore [manual certificate distribution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#manual-certs) should apply and a possible sequence of steps could thus be:

1. copy certificates and keys in `/etc/kubernetes/pki/{ca.*,sa.*,front-proxy-sa.*,etcd/ca.*}` from the first to the new master node
2. run `kubeadm token create --print-join-command` on the first master node
3. run printed `kubeadm join` command with the additional argument `--experimental-control-plane` on the new master node

Is this the correct procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#stacked-control-plane-and-etcd-nodes), this command provides a new decription key:

```
kubeadm init phase upload-certs --experimental-upload-certs
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to answers given is to use `kubeadm` to manage certificates by uploading the certificates as a secret to `kube-system` (it will expire in 2 hours). There is no need to pass a certificate key in the init phase

So you can do

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT"
```

And then at a later time

```
kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs
```

That command will output the certificate key you can use for the secret created

```
kubeadm join LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT --token <token> \     
--discovery-token-ca-cert-hash <hash> \
--control-plane \
--certificate-key <key from previous commmand>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this in 1.17 and finally found this command would give pre-generate a certificate key that I could use in both `kubeadmn init` and `kubeadmn join`. For it to work the you need to pass `--upload-certs` as well as when you run `kubeadmn init` similar to what you noted for 1.14.

`# generate a certificate-key to be used
kubeadm alpha certs certificate-key`

`# initialize first master using above key, --upload-certs (and other parameters)
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint $API_SERVER:6443 --upload-certs --apiserver-cert-extra-sans $API_SERVER  --certificate-key $CERT-KEY`

`# join other masters using the same certificate-key 
kubeadm join $API_SERVER:6443 --token $TOKEN --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash $CAHASH --control-plane --certificate-key $CERT-KEY`