# adding master to Kubernetes cluster: cluster doesn't have a stable controlPlaneEndpoint address

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

How can I add a second master to the control plane of an existing Kubernetes 1.14 cluster?
The [available documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#manual-certs) apparently assumes that both masters (in stacked control plane and etcd nodes) are created at the same time. I have created my first master already a while ago with [`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#initializing-your-master), so I don't have a `kubeadm-config.yaml` as referred to by this documentation.

I have tried the following instead:

```
kubeadm join ... --token ... --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash ... \
  --experimental-control-plane --certificate-key ...
```

The part `kubeadm join ... --token ... --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash ...` is what is suggested when running `kubeadm token create --print-join-command` on the first master; it normally serves for adding another worker. `--experimental-control-plane` is for adding another master instead. The key in `--certificate-key ...` is as suggested by running [`kubeadm init phase upload-certs --experimental-upload-certs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55850990/9164810) on the first master.

I receive the following errors:

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. 
The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
error execution phase preflight: 
One or more conditions for hosting a new control plane instance is not satisfied.

unable to add a new control plane instance a cluster that doesn't have a stable
controlPlaneEndpoint address

Please ensure that:
* The cluster has a stable controlPlaneEndpoint address.
* The certificates that must be shared among control plane instances are provided.
```

What does it mean for my cluster not to have a stable `controlPlaneEndpoint` address? Could this be related to `controlPlaneEndpoint` in the output from `kubectl -n kube-system get configmap kubeadm-config -o yaml` currently being an empty string? How can I overcome this situation?

Comment: are you able to fix your issue, i am in same situation.

Answer (score 4):

As per [HA - Create load balancer for kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#create-load-balancer-for-kube-apiserver):

> - In a cloud environment you should place your control plane nodes    behind a TCP forwarding load balancer. This load balancer distributes 
>     traffic to all healthy control plane nodes in its target list. The 
>     health check for an apiserver is a TCP check on the port the
>     kube-apiserver listens on (default value `:6443`).
> - The load balancer must be able to communicate with all control plane nodes on the apiserver port. It must also allow incoming traffic
>     on its listening port.
> - **Make sure the address of the load balancer
>     always matches the address of kubeadm’s `ControlPlaneEndpoint`.**

To set `ControlPlaneEndpoint` config, you should use `kubeadm` with the `--config` flag. Take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#stacked-control-plane-and-etcd-nodes) for a config file example:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: stable
controlPlaneEndpoint: "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT"
```

*Kubeadm config files examples are scattered across many documentation sections. I recommend that you read the [`/apis/kubeadm/v1beta1`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta1) GoDoc, which have fully populated examples of YAML files used by multiple kubeadm configuration types.*

---

If you are configuring a self-hosted control-plane, consider using the [`kubeadm alpha selfhosting`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#self-hosting) feature:

> [..] key components such as the API server, controller manager, and
>   scheduler run as DaemonSet pods configured via the Kubernetes API
>   instead of static pods configured in the kubelet via static files.

This PR ([#59371](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/59371)) may clarify the differences of using a self-hosted config.

Comment: Do you know what `kubeadm init --config ...` will do to the control plane of my existing cluster? I would like to turn my existing non-HA cluster into a HA cluster by just adding extra master nodes ("on-the-fly", so to speak, and without loosing the existing control plane in the process). Don't know if that's feasible, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the certificates ( etcd/api server/ca etc. ) from the existing master and place on the second master.
then run kubeadm init script. since the certs are already present the cert creation step is skipped and rest of the cluster initialization steps are resumed.

Comment: Shouldn't `kubeadm init phase upload-certs --experimental-upload-certs` and the reference to `--certificate-key ...` not take care of this? The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#manual-certs) IMO describes `--experimental-upload-certs` as an alternative to manual certificate distribution.

Comment: havent used it though. it might be another way to do it. i havent used it and cant comment on it. i suggested the approach that i followed and it worked

Comment: the certs are located in /etc/kubernetes/pki/

Comment: havent come across cluster not having a stable controlPlaneEndpoint address. when you have multiple masters each master is going to have one api endpoint address. you need to load balance the api server endpoints across the masters

Comment: @PEkambaram After copying all certs, its not working it gives error that certificate is not valid for MASTER2, its only valid for MASTER1 (from where we copied)

Comment: Getting this same issue with kubeadm 1.18.9. First node has a working endpoint that is working fine. I've come to the conclusion tha t kubeadm is just a pile of dung. We've tried to use it for every version of kube going back to 1.14 and abandon it every time. Prolyl designed for simple mom and pop shops. Its completely garbage. Doesnt even have structured json output or accept structured json.

Answer (score 0):

Edit you configmap and add controlplane address.

```
kubectl edit cm -n kubesystem kubeadm-config
```

[image]

Restart **kube-apiserver** pod. And then join the control-plane nodes.