# Join/extend a Windows Server to a Istio Mesh?

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, istio

I have and Istio mesh on baremetal and I wish to join a Windows Server to the a istio mesh

Comment: Please provide more information. Do you have Istio Mesh in Minikube in Windows and want to add another Windows VM to Mesh or do you have Istio Mesh on Linux and want to add Win VM. Also could you provide more information about Mesh?

Answer (score 0):

Istio will automatically be applied across your kubernetes cluster so will be perfectly happy with machines (virtual or physical) as soon as they are added to your kubernetes cluster.

So assuming you have correctly configured your virtual machine (specifically network interfaces), you can do a kubeadm join

Configuring VMs: https://medium.com/@shalithasuranga/simulating-a-data-center-with-virtual-machines-in-your-computer-76a434c02585

Joining kubernetes cluster:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50198349/10461045

Comment: All the links you provided where about joining Linux based machine to the cluster what I asked was I want to join a windows machine to the istio mesh

Comment: I have removed the worlds virtual machine from my question cause they wheeler not relevant